# javascript promises: returning promises with another return inside results in same behavior as using with out 2nd return

Tags: javascript

I was trying out Promises and have the 2 functions below.  I was calling `test1()` and then using `then()` to call `test2()`.  The behavior worked as expected with `test1 completed` logged after 3 seconds and then immediately logging `test2 completed`.  My question is that when I add another `return` before the `setTimeout`, it still works the same.  Why would that be the case?

```
function test1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
           console.log("test1 completed");
           resolve(true);
        }, 3000);
    });

    // return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
    //     return setTimeout(() => {
    //        console.log("test1 completed");
    //        resolve(true);
    //     }, 3000);
    // });

}

function test2() {
    console.log("test2 completed");
}
```

Comment: return inside the Promise executor has no effect at all - the returned value doesn't *go* anywhere and is not handled by anything so has no effect on how the promise behaves

Comment: "when I add another return before the setTimeout, it still works the same" <= how is that true?  If you return before your setTimeout, the resolve will never be called.

Comment: look at the commented code @Taplar - `return setTimeout(()` ... see, `return` added before (and, importantly, on the same line as) `setTimeout`

Comment: Ok, that explains it.  And Bravo's comment explains why there is no change.  The timeout will still happen, regardless of a return like that or not.